# Is it possible to convert the USNG grid to a perfect square 10mx10m fishnet at CONUS scale?

Tags: coordinate-system, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I realize this is a ridiculous question, so please forgive in advance.

Would it be possible to generate a 10m x 10m grid at CONUS scale, without any non-square polygons at the Grid Zone Junctions (GZJs)? The desired result would have all GZJs removed from the USNG, and could be served to the web as a vector tile layer. Instead of slivers or polygons at the GZJs, the desired result would look like a fishnet containing perfect squares throughout.

I don't think just generating a fishnet would accomplish this result, because generating 10m x 10m fishnet vector polygons would be significantly computationally burdensome. My question then, is do you think this gird be produced at CONUS-scale without creating some kind of monster vector shapefile? I can't use rasters to solve this problem, as the grid cells are designed to be attributed with multiple variables.

Again, I understand this doesn't really make sense, but I was wondering if anyone had any bright ideas as to how this might be accomplished.

[image: Remove polygons at GZJs]

Comment: If you're going to use several UTM zones, then grid junctions are kind of inevitable, since it's not a continuous projection, breaks have to occur somewhere. If you used a single continuous projection for your whole area of interest, then you could generate a perfect grid throughout the whole area, but then projection distortions might be greater, meaning some of your cells wouldn't represent exactly 10 meters on the field. Maybe close, but most likely not as close as UTM would be.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to generate a perfect square grid, and of equal dimensions, on the Earth without having shifts, breaks of distortions somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, we ended up using Google Plus codes. Thanks all! https://grid.plus.codes/